# Navigation bar is too long on progressbar theme, can it wrap?

Tags: beamer

My navigation bar at the top of each slide (that links to each section) has too many sections. I would like to keep the bar and keep each section but I would like to wrap it i.e. have it on two lines.

Is that possible?

I am using `compress` and I am using [`progressbar`](http://recherche.noiraudes.net/fr/LaTeX.php) as a theme.

Comment: Please indicate which beamer theme you use at present. Also, have you tried using the class option `compress`, as in `\documentclass[compress]{beamer}`? With this option, beamer will try to make all navigation bars "as small as possible."

Comment: Edited to add this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could redefine the `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal` command
and wrap the sections with a parbox.

Here is a quick & dirty example of it could be done in general:

```
\makeatletter
\def\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal#1#2#3{%
 \hbox to #1{{%
   \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
   #2\hskip.3cm%
   \newdimen\tmp@parbox%
   \setlength\tmp@parbox{#1}%
   \addtolength\tmp@parbox{-.6cm}%
   \parbox{\tmp@parbox}{\raggedleft%
     \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
     \setbox\beamer@sectionbox=\hbox{}%
     \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
     \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
     \hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill\dohead%
     \box\beamer@sectionbox}\hfil\hskip.3cm%
     #3}}}
\makeatother
```

Here is a complete example for the `progressbar` theme, with increased headline height.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{progressbar}
\progressbaroptions{headline=sections}

\makeatletter
\def\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal#1#2#3{%
  \hbox to #1{{%
    \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
    #2\hskip.3cm%
    \newdimen\tmp@parbox%
    \setlength\tmp@parbox{#1}%
    \addtolength\tmp@parbox{-.6cm}%
    \parbox{\tmp@parbox}{\raggedleft%
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
      \setbox\beamer@sectionbox=\hbox{}%
      \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
      \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
      \hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill\dohead%
      \box\beamer@sectionbox}\hfil\hskip.3cm%
      #3}}}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \edef\tempa{sections}
  \ifx\progressbar@headline\tempa
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorestructure.bg=true,wd=\paperwidth,ht=8ex,dp=1.125ex]{structure.fg}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}%\hskip0pt plus1filll}{}%
    \vspace*{0mm}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \else
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,dp=1.125ex]{structure.fg}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{First very long section name}
\section{Second very long section name}
\section{Third very long section name}
\section{Fourth very long section name}
\section{Fifth very long section name}

\begin{frame}{Title}
Content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you wrote.  I tried incorporating your example into my code and got a 'weird error'. Is there perhaps a simpler way to make the text on the sections wrap around?

Comment: @iKs Try including the code in the preamble by putting the code between `\makeatletter .....  \makeatother`.

Comment: Sry, forgot to mention this. Added the makeat stuff to the example. The example is the original beamer implementation with an added parbox including basic width calculation.

Comment: Can you please complete your code into a full working example with one/two dummy frames? It's precisely the cases as above in the comments that we are trying to avoid. Besides, people who ends up on this page directly from Google might have none to little initial (La)TeX knowledge.

Comment: @ejoerns is it possible to modify `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal` to add progress dots under the section header (similar to the dots that appear with `\sectionnavigation`)? Thank you.