# How to remove navigational circles and fit the navigation bar titles in Frankfurt beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames

I'm using the `Frankfurt` theme and I have two questions about it:

1. There are navigational circles that appear when I create subsections. They are equal to the number of pages in that section which is annoying because they are too many. I tried the following two solutions to remove them but both didn't work

   ```
   \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty  
   \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
   ```
2. If I have many sections with relatively long titles, the titles don't fit in the navigation bar and they got trimmed. Is there a way to make the titles appear in two lines instead of one trimmed line?

Comment: Hi Ahmed, [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/9043)! I removed the thanks at the end. This is just the style here. Thanks is best expressed in the upvoting of answers that help you.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for that. Sorry it's my first time. By the way, is there something I did that prevents people from posting answers to my question ?

Comment: No need to be sorry! Sometimes these can take a while to get attention. A good way of getting more attention is to include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/9043), and then people can copy, paste and play with the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. The navigation symbols are those normally placed at the bottom.
   To remove the circles you mentioned you can use:

   ```
   \setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}
   ```
2. Maybe you could use my answer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45348/navigation-bar-is-too-long-on-progressbar-theme-can-it-wrap/45365#45365)?