# Question Related to Suppressing Navigation Circles in Beamer

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames

This question is in reference to [How to remove navigational circles and fit the navigation bar titles in Frankfurt beamer theme?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45477/how-to-remove-navigational-circles-and-fit-the-navigation-bar-titles-in-frankfur) (I would simply add a comment to diabonas' answer, but I don't have enough reputation - is there a way around this?)

Anyway, I wanted to achieve a similar result to the user who posted that question, and the solution provided works well, except I would prefer the most recently highlighted circle to remain highlighted whilst we set `\miniframesoff`. How could I go modifying the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand this you wish to still have the white dot for the current subsection, but all other subsection dots should be invisible.  This can be achieved by using the `beamer` template `mini frame in other subsection`, which takes an optional pair of arguments `[default][xx]`.  Here `xx` is a percentage, and these circles will be given a color that is `xx` percent of the foreground and `100-xx` percent of the background.  Thus putting `xx` to `0` yields invisible circles.  Here is a sample image for the third subsection of the first section:

[image: Sample third subsection]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}[default][0]

\section{Start}

\subsection{Sub1}

\begin{frame}
  Text.
\end{frame}

\subsection{Sub2}

\begin{frame}
  Text.
\end{frame}

\subsection{Sub3}

\begin{frame}
  Text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```