# Changing the font family of the mini-navigation in the 'Frankfurt' beamer theme

Tags: beamer, fonts, header-footer, mini-frames

I am currently in process of tweaking the look of my beamer presentation and would like the navigational elements (TOC and mini-navigation, that is shipped alongside the Frankfurt theme) to use Sans-Serif fonts, while the rest of the presentation is supposed to use Roman fonts.

This wasn't such a problem for the TOC, but I have trouble correctly selecting the text above the navigational circles.

Referring to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45594/24604), I tried to use `mini`, but that didn't change anything.

Here is the current code snippet:

```
\setbeamerfont{mini}{family=\sf}
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{size=\scriptsize,family=\sf}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\tiny,family=\sf}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid I'm not completely sure what you want to achieve, as sans fonts are the same as sans-serif fonts, that is to say fonts without the little lines at the end of the strokes (like the one used on this website). I guess you're using something like

```
\usefonttheme{serif}
```

to get a serif typeface for the normal text of your presentation, but you still want to retain the default sans-serif typeface in the headline. This can be achieved by changing the `beamer` theme `section in head/foot`:

```
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
```

(using `\sffamily` instead of the [deprecated `\sf`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc)).

#### Full example code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection}
\frame{Serif typeface}\frame{Serif typeface}\frame{Serif typeface}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection}
\frame{Serif typeface}\frame{Serif typeface}\frame{Serif typeface}\frame{Serif typeface}\frame{Serif typeface}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection}
\frame{Serif typeface}\frame{Serif typeface}
\end{document}
```

[image: frame showing text in serif typeface in combination with a sans-serif header]

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you, of course I meant Serif/Roman fonts and Sans-Serif fonts, not Sans fonts and Sans-Serif fonts. I've updated the question with the correct terms. In the end, your solution achieves what I wanted, thank you for your contribution.