# Reduce height of sections box in beamer?

Tags: beamer, sectioning

So essentially I would like to do this: [Is it possible to reduce the height of the frame title box in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254814/is-it-possible-to-reduce-the-height-of-the-frame-title-box-in-beamer)
... but for the sections box in a beamer presentation. In different words: **How do you adjust the height of the sections box in beamer?**

I currently use the following template:

```
    \documentclass[]{beamer}
    
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}%gets rid of bottom navigation bars
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}%gets rid of footer
    
    \useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
    \setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
        \nointerlineskip%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.2ex]{frametitle}
            \hspace*{1ex}\insertframetitle%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }
    
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red,bg=black}
    \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red}
    
    \setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{\hfill\bfseries\insertsectionhead}
    \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=red,fg=black}
    \setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=red,bg=black}
    \setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=red,bg=black}
    \setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}[default][30]
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \section{Hello}
    \begin{frame}{Hello}
        Hello
    \end{frame}
        
    \end{document}
```

The reason I would like to change the section height manually is that there seems to be a difference between TeX Live 2015 and TeX Live 2018 when compiling the above code. In the former I get:
[image]

while in the latter I get:
[image]

I would like to reproduce the TeX Live 2015 behavior by adapting the TeX Live 2018 behavior manually. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related, but do not help me unfortunately: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45348/navigation-bar-is-too-long-on-progressbar-theme-can-it-wrap/45365#45365 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45477/how-to-remove-navigational-circles-and-fit-the-navigation-bar-titles-in-frankfur

Answer (score 2):

It would appear your 2015 code was partially faulty there should have been be two rows one of text and one of  symbols in the red area then one bigger one in the Black. But the second red row was malformed. I have shuffled the order of some of your rows thus altering some stability whilst testing. Beware changing order can easily affect the header making it "fuzzy" or otherwise.

The relative position of theme elements is critical to good behaviour. See how the whole structure can change if you simply replace the final Frankfurt with Antibes

The easiest way to change the size of the top bar is set default starting font to 8pt.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[8pt]{beamer}

%\usetheme{Frankfurt} % use at bottom of preamble for fuzzy edges (top=sharp)
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}%gets rid of bottom navigation bars
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}%gets rid of footer
    \usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}
    \setbeamerfont*{title}{shape=\itshape,family=\rmfamily}

    \setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{\bfseries\insertsectionhead}
    \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=red,fg=black}
    \setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=red,bg=black}
    \setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=red,bg=black}
    \setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}[default][30]
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red,bg=black}
    \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red}

    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
        \nointerlineskip%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.2ex]{frametitle}
            \hspace*{1ex}\insertframetitle%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }
    \useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
    \setbeamertemplate{miniframes}{\small}

\usetheme{Frankfurt} % use here at bottom of preamble for fuzzy edges (top=sharp)

    \begin{document}

    \section{\tiny Hello There}
    \begin{frame}{Hello}
        Hello
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{World}
        World
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Please note that removing the bullets in the red box was intentional. I would really like to reproduce the 2015 Version outcome of the code I gave.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was [provided](https://pastebin.com/aaHN9wCi) by Stackoverflow user [samcarter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2777074/samcarter) in the [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193903/duck-overflow). I am posting it here because it solved my problem.

Here is a template that reproduces the 2015 behavior of the code in the question when it is run with TeX Live 2018.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}%gets rid of bottom navigation bars
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}%gets rid of footer

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.2ex]{frametitle}
        \hspace*{1ex}\insertframetitle%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{\hfill\bfseries\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=red,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=red,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=red,bg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}[default][30]

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip1pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}\vskip1pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Hello}
\begin{frame}{Hello}
    Hello
\end{frame}

\section{Hello}
\begin{frame}{Hello}
    Hello
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The relevant additional bit is

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip1pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}\vskip1pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother
```