# Beamer headline too long

Tags: beamer, header-footer

When creating a beamer presentation in LaTeX, I have so many sections and frames, that the headline with the navigation bar is too long for the frame. Also, the table of contents is too long. I know that I can change the fontsize for the TOC, but is there a possibility to arrange the TOC in 2 (or more) columns? And is it possible to arrange the headline in more then 1 (say, 2) lines?

Working example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame} \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections] \end{frame}
\section{Abschnitt} \subsection{Abschnitt} \begin{frame} Abschnitt \end{frame}
\section{Abschnitt} \subsection{Abschnitt} \begin{frame} Abschnitt \end{frame}
\section{Abschnitt} \subsection{Abschnitt} \begin{frame} Abschnitt \end{frame}
\section{Abschnitt} \subsection{Abschnitt} \begin{frame} Abschnitt \end{frame}
\section{Abschnitt} \subsection{Abschnitt} \begin{frame} Abschnitt \end{frame}
\section{Abschnitt} \subsection{Abschnitt} \begin{frame} Abschnitt \end{frame}
\section{Abschnitt} \subsection{Abschnitt} \begin{frame} Abschnitt \end{frame}
\section{Abschnitt} \subsection{Abschnitt} \begin{frame} Abschnitt \end{frame}
\section{Abschnitt} \subsection{Abschnitt} \begin{frame} Abschnitt \end{frame}
\section{Abschnitt} \subsection{Abschnitt} \begin{frame} Abschnitt \end{frame}
\section{Abschnitt} \subsection{Abschnitt} \begin{frame} Abschnitt \end{frame}
\section{Abschnitt} \subsection{Abschnitt} \begin{frame} Abschnitt \end{frame}
\section{Abschnitt} \subsection{Abschnitt} \begin{frame} Abschnitt \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: The first question has been solved, thx to samcarter. For the second question the code in the given link does not work for me. Since I am using the theme Frankfurt, I thought I had to exchange `\progressbaroptions{headline=sections}` by `\Frankfurtoptions{headline=sections}` but this does not work. If I leave away that line, no headline at all is shown.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How long are your Beamer presentations? Unless they're several hours long, is there a benefit -- to your audience, and to you -- to having so many sectioning commands? Not every frame needs a sectioning command.

Comment: @Mico: Thx. The presentation I am now working on will be about 3-4 hours long (maybe even longer). Not like in the example above, every section consits of more than one frame.

Comment: You may (should ?) use `\part`...

Comment: Hi! Your question contains two separate questions. As far as I see, the first question about multi-column ToC is answered in [Beamer: Vertical alignment of multi-column ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109748/beamer-vertical-alignment-of-multi-column-toc?lq=1), the second question about multi-line navigation bullets in [Navigation bar is too long on progressbar theme, can it wrap?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45348/navigation-bar-is-too-long-on-progressbar-theme-can-it-wrap?lq=1). (Thanks to **samcarter** for pointing these out.)

Comment: @Martin: I was accepting your edit meanwhile mods merge your account. Please, notice that progress bar theme is a bit different with respect to themes native in Beamer. Hence, with Frankfurt, you don't have `\Franfkfurtoptions` way to customize the theme. The beameruserguide will tell you how to do.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: @Claudio: I've looked in the beameruserguide but couldnt find how I have to modify the code (especially since `\progressbar` is used inside the code, too)

Comment: @Martin: if you use Frankfurt theme, there is no progessbar (unless you add it manually). Hence, you can't use explicit facilities introduced by progress bar theme: one of them, I suppose, is the `\progressbaroptions`. You have to go with `\setbeamertemplate` instead.

Comment: @Claudio: Thx, but what do I have to write inside `\setbeamertemplate` to get a multi-line navigationbar?