# Get dots under Section Heading for Custom Beamer Template

Tags: beamer, formatting, positioning, presentations

I am using a modified version of the `ua-theme` by Nico Schlomer.

https://github.com/nschloe/ua-beamer/blob/master/theme/beamerouterthemeUniversiteitAntwerpen.sty

Using the posting on:

[Navigation bar is too long on progressbar theme, can it wrap?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45348/navigation-bar-is-too-long-on-progressbar-theme-can-it-wrap?rq=1)

I was able to get section headings that wrap on to multiple lines.

I would like to get dots under section headings:

[image: get dots]

Here is a minimal example:

I have the following file called `beamerouterthemeUniversityCustom.sty'

```
% Original by Nico Schlomer, Copyright 2009--2011
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.


% Custom Navigation
\def\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal#1#2#3{%
  \hbox to #1{{%
    \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
    #2\hskip.3cm%
    \newdimen\tmp@parbox%
    \setlength\tmp@parbox{#1}%
    \addtolength\tmp@parbox{-.6cm}%
    \parbox{\tmp@parbox}{\raggedleft%
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
      \setbox\beamer@sectionbox=\hbox{}%
      \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
      \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
      \hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill\dohead%
      \box\beamer@sectionbox}\hfil\hskip.3cm%
      #3}}}


\RequirePackage{ifthen}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% *** DEFINE LENGTHS <<<
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\margin}
\setlength{\margin}{0.8832cm}% 

\newlength{\ulogoheight}
\setlength{\ulogoheight}{0.90066895151709692cm}% 
\ifbeamer@dark\else%
\fi

\ifthenelse{ \boolean{beamer@dark} \OR \(\boolean{beamer@darktitle}\AND\c@framenumber=1\) }{%
  \defbeamertemplate*{headline}{univ theme}%
  {
    % page number
    \ifbeamer@framenumber%
      \ifnum\c@framenumber=1\else
       \pgftext[right,top,at=\pgfpoint{\paperwidth-\margin}{-0.04\paperheight}]{%
          \usebeamerfont{frame number in head}%
          \usebeamercolor[fg]{frame number in head}%
          \insertframenumber{}%
          \ifbeamer@totalframenumber%
            /\inserttotalframenumber%
          \fi
        }%
      \fi
    \fi%
  }%
}{
  \newlength{\logotopmargin}%
  \setlength{\logotopmargin}{0.300cm}%  
  \defbeamertemplate*{headline}{univ theme}%
  {%
    \vskip\logotopmargin%
    \hskip\margin%
    \ifthenelse{ \boolean{beamer@dark} \OR \(\boolean{beamer@darktitle}\AND\c@framenumber=1\) }
    {%
      \vskip5cm
    }
{
\hspace*{-2.0cm}
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.35\textwidth}
\centering
    \text{Logo here later}
\end{minipage}% <---------------- Note the use of "%"
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedright
\hbox{

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=8ex,dp=1.125ex]{structure.fg}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{0.7\paperwidth}{}{}
       \vspace*{0mm}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%

}
\end{minipage}
    }
  }
}
```

I also have a file called `beamerthemeUniversityCustom.sty`:

```
% Original from 2009--2011 by Nico Schlomer
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.

\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}

\newif\ifbeamer@dark
\beamer@darkfalse
\DeclareOptionBeamer{dark}{\beamer@darktrue}

\newif\ifbeamer@darktitle
\beamer@darktitlefalse
\DeclareOptionBeamer{darktitle}{\beamer@darktitletrue}

\mode<presentation>

\useoutertheme{UniversityCustom}
```

My main file is `presentation.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usetheme{UniversityCustom}


\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded=false, shadow=false]

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Outline}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
        \normalsize{\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]}
\end{frame}
}

\makeatletter
  \beamer@compressfalse
\makeatother


\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{My Name}
\institute{My University}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Section 1}
Text goes here
\end{frame}


\section{Section 2}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Section 2}
Text goes here
\end{frame}


\section{Section 3}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Section 3}
Text goes here
\end{frame}


\section{Section 4}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Section 4}
Text goes here
\end{frame}


\section{Section 5}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Section 5}
Text goes here
\end{frame}


\section{Section 6}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Section 6}
Text goes here
\end{frame}



\section{Section 7}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Section 7}
Text goes here
\end{frame}


\section{Section 8}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Section 8}
Text goes here
\end{frame}

\section{Section 9}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Section 9}
Text goes here
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I believe I need to change the `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal` in order to get dots to appear under the sections headings but I have not been able to figure this out. Can someone help please?

Thank you for looking at my post.