# Beamer Heading Break New Line

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, sectioning, header-footer, frame-title

I have the following code with many sections:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{apresentacao}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}

\newcounter{saveenumi}
\newcommand{\seti}{\setcounter{saveenumi}{\value{enumi}}}
\newcommand{\conti}{\setcounter{enumi}{\value{saveenumi}}}

\resetcounteronoverlays{saveenumi}

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{
  %\insertslidenavigationsymbol     
  %\insertframenavigationsymbol     
  %\insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol    
  %\insertsectionnavigationsymbol   
  %\insertdocnavigationsymbol   
  %\insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol 
 % \hspace{1em}     
  %\usebeamerfont{footline}     
  %\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber 
%}

% Numeração das Páginas
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
    \fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
  \hspace{5em}%
  \ifnum\insertframenumber>0
    \insertframenumber~/~\inserttotalframenumber
  \fi
}

\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}

% Títlo da disciplina
\title[Programação Web II]{
  \textbf{\textcolor{mycolor}{Programação Web II}}}
  
% Subtítulo da apresentação
\subtitle{\textcolor{white}{Processamento de Formulário com PHP}}

% Autor da apresentação com e-mail.
\author[Prof. Ricardo Ramos de Oliveira]{
  \textbf{Prof. Ricardo Ramos de Oliveira} \medskip
  {\small \url{ricardo.ramos@ifsuldeminas.edu.br}}}
  
% Informações sobre a instituição...

\institute[]{
\makebox[60pt][l]{%
  \raisebox{-\totalheight}[0pt][20pt]{%
  
    \includegraphics[scale=0.08]{pocos-de-caldas-bw}}}%

\small{\textbf{Instituto Federal do Sul de Minas Gerais}}\\\scriptsize{Campus Poços de Caldas}
\vspace{1.5cm}

\scriptsize{\textbf{Curso de Engenharia de computação}}\\
\tiny{8º Período}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\centering\tiny{05 de dezembro de 2020}

}

% Permite exibir o nome IFSULDEMINAS ao longo dos slides.
\date[IFSULDEMINAS]{
}

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{qbk}

\begin{frame}[plain, noframenumbering]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
  \frametitle{\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont Sumário}

  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Processamento de Formulário}

\begin{frame}[<+->]
  \frametitle{\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont Formulário}

    \Large{}
    \begin{itemize}
      \justifying
      \item Formulários são utilizados na web para envio de informações do cliente para o servidor;
      \item Como processar as informações de um formulário com o PHP?
      \item No PHP, essas informações são enviadas através das variáveis \\ globais \textbf{\$\_GET} e \textbf{\$\_POST};      
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The final result:

[image]

How should I do to break the line and display the other sections on the new line below? Because the other sections are not showing up.

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) allowing others to reproduce the output you get. Currently, your code is not compilable since image files and custom defined colors are ot available to others. Additionally, `apresentacao.sty` is not a standard package. If I comment it out and substitute the colors and images by available ones, I get an entirely different output than the screenshot you show.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45365/36296 , but without having access to "apresentacao.sty" that's just a guess